# How do I populate HTML tables with an ajax response?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

**I** have a laravel blade view/page that I'd like to update without refreshing the page.

The blade.php code is working fine and retrieving data from a MySQL database - but the ajax/javascript isn't.

Apparently my AJAX calls are not even returning JSON but an object.

I come from a background of C# and never touched ajax/javascript/php in my life and I'd appreciate it if anyone could help me.

The controller.php works and returns the data I need which LOOKS like json but apparently isn't json.

What I would like to do is refresh the page a user is on (without reloading it), grab the data from a MySQL database and update the pre-existing tables with this new data - if there is any new data.

view.blade.php:

```
<table class="table custom--table" id="mainTable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>@lang('ID')</th>
        <th>@lang('Name')</th>
        <th>@lang('Date')</th>
        <th>@lang('Details')</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    @forelse($items as $data)
        <tr>
            <td data-label="@lang('ID')">
                {{ $loop->index + 1 }}
            </td>
            <td data-label="@lang('Name')">{{ $data->name }}</td>
            <td data-label="@lang('Date')">{{ $data->created_at }}</td>
            <td id="detailz" data-label="@lang('Details')">{{ $data->details }}</td>
        </tr>
    @empty
        <tr>
            <td colspan="100%" class="text-center justify-content-center">@lang('No data.')</td>
        </tr>
    @endforelse
  </tbody>
</table>
```

AJAX: (Not working)

```
function updatePost() {
setInterval(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "{{route('user.posts.update')}}", // Route works.
        success: function( response ){

            $('#mainTable')[0].reset();
             $("tbody").html("");
             $.each(response, function( index, value ) {
                var row = $("<tr><td>"
                            + value.name + "</td><td>"
                            + value.details + "</td><td>"
                            + value.created_at + "</td><td>");

                $("tbody").append(row);
            });

        },
        error: function( response ){
            console.log("Error!");
            console.log(response);
        }
    });
}, 5000); // every 5s
```

controller.php:

```
  public function postUpdate(){
      $pageTitle = 'Post Update';
      $data = DataHistory::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->latest()->paginate(getPaginate());
      return response()->json($data);
    }
```

I've tried many different methods in ajax but apparently I can't seem to access the inner elements of the data.

Here's a sample of the data:

```
{
    "current_page":1,
    "data":[
        {
            "id":34,
            "user_id":1,
            "name":"RANDOM NAME DATA",
            "details":"RANDOM DETAILS",
            "created_at":"2022-11-16T15:02:56.000000Z"
        },{
            "id":32,
            "user_id":1,
            "name":"RANDOM NAME DATA 2",
            "details":"RANDOM DETAILS 2",
            "created_at":"2022-11-16T10:19:29.000000Z"
        },
    "first_page_url":"https:\/\/xyz.com/posts/update/?page=1",
    "from":1,
    "last_page":1,
    "last_page_url":"https:\/\/xyz.com/posts/update/?page=1",
    "links":[
        {
            "url":null,
            "label":"&laquo; Previous",
            "active":false
        },{
            "url":"https:\/\/xyz.com/posts/update/?page=1",
            "label":"1",
            "active":true
        },{
            "url":null,
            "label":"Next &raquo;",
            "active":false
        }
    ],
    "next_page_url":null,
    "path":"https:\/\/xyz.com/posts/update/",
    "per_page":20,
    "prev_page_url":null,
    "to":7,
    "total":7
}
```

How will I be able to achieve this? Am I going in the right direction?

Comment: What you have there is valid JSON, but its an object not an array. There's an array within it, in the `data` property. So if you loop through response.data I expect you'd have more luck.

Comment: Also you may need to add `dataType: "json"` to your ajax options so that jquery parses the json string into a js object before you try to process it

Comment: question does not clearly indicate technology and framework,.

Comment: `$.each(response.data, function...`

Comment: Thanks @ADyson, it's working now! Spent 3 hours on this issue.

Comment: No worries. I suggest you work on your understanding of the structure of JSON objects then, ensuring you know about objects, arrays and properties, and how they're represented :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have there is valid JSON, but its an object not an array. There's an array within it, in the `data` property. So if you loop through `response.data` it will work:

```
$.each(response.data, function( index, value ) {
```

Answer (score 0):

You would want to iterate the response property `data`

```
         $.each(response.data, function( index, value ) {
```

so that `value.name` will actually contain the values from these objects from your demo data:

```
    {
        "id":34,
        "user_id":1,
        "name":"RANDOM NAME DATA",
        "details":"RANDOM DETAILS",
        "created_at":"2022-11-16T15:02:56.000000Z"
    },{
        "id":32,
        "user_id":1,
        "name":"RANDOM NAME DATA 2",
        "details":"RANDOM DETAILS 2",
        "created_at":"2022-11-16T10:19:29.000000Z"
    },
```